# Exponentiation of a quadratic Hamiltonian in Fermionic Creation/Anihilation operators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, fermions

I have the following Hamiltonian $$\mathcal{H}=e^{i\phi}a^{\dagger}_1a^{\dagger}_2+e^{-i\phi}a_2a_1,$$ where $a_1$ and ${a_2}$ are the annihilation operators of two distinct fermionic modes and satisfy the Fermionic Conmutation Relations $$\{a_i,a_j\}=0 ,\quad \{a_i^\dagger,a_j\}=\delta_{ij}\mathcal{I},$$
where $\mathcal{I}$ is the identity.

I want to find the exponential $$S=e^{i\mathcal{H}t}$$ of such Hamiltonian. Through simple calculation I found that:

$$S=i\mathcal{H}\sin(t)+\mathcal{I}_d+\mathcal{H}^2\left(-\frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^4}{4!}+...\right)$$

So it makes me suspect that $\mathcal{H}^2=\mathcal{I}$ in order to get the cosine expansion, but I am unable to prove it.